# Not able to use a certain word for a function name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this basic app that i am working on in Laravel. A user asks a query and other users can comment on it.

I have this relationship built in the Comment model-

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function query()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Query::class);
    }
}
```

When i run `php artisan tinker` and create a new instance like so-

```
$comment = new App\Comment
```

I get an **error**-

```
Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::query() non static in class App\Comment
```

The problem i figured was with the name of the function **'query'**. Because if i change the name to anything else, it works. I don't get any error.

I found out that there is a function in `lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` with the name **'query'** that has this code in it-

```
public static function query()
{
    return (new static)->newQuery();
}
```

So, am I not allowed to use the word **'query'** to name the function in my model?

Comment: You can if you mean to override it. Otherwise, choose another name.

Comment: Wasn't it simpler to _rename_ the method instead of even asking here? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Method query() is used in Model](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query). So, only rename your method to avoid bad behavior.